# SQL Server Stored Procedure Creating Duplicates

Tags: asp.net, sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2000

I am running a website using SQL Server 2008 and ASP.NET 4.0. I am trying to trace an issue down that my stored procedure is creating duplicate entries for the same date. Originally I thought this may be a couple post issue but the duplicates are recording the same date down to the milliseconds. One of the duplicates is at :'2013-04-26 15:48:28.323' All of the data is exactly the same except for the id.

`@check_date` is an input into the stored procedure which gives us the particular date we are looking at (entries are maid daily)

`@formHeaderId` is grabbed earlier in the stored procedure, getting the header ID as this is a detail table with a 1 to many relationship with the header.

The `@getdate()` entry is where I found the duplicate entries, there are entries with the exact `getdate()` values for different rows.

This doesn't occur with each entry either, it is randomly occurring in the application.

```
select @formHeaderId=stage2_checklist_header_id 
from stage2_checklist_header 
where environmental_forms_id=@envFormId
and checklist_monthyear=@inspected_month 
order by start_date desc

if @formHeaderId = 0 begin

    insert into stage2_checklist_header(
        environmental_forms_id      
        ,start_date 
        ,checklist_monthyear
        ,st2h_load_date )
    values( @envFormId
            ,@check_date 
            ,@inspected_month 
            ,getdate())

    set @formHeaderId = scope_identity() 
    print 'inserted new header record ' + cast(@formHeaderId as varchar(50))

end 

IF (NOT EXISTS(
       SELECT *
         FROM stage2_checklist_detail
        WHERE  stage2_checklist_header_id = @formHeaderId
          AND check_date = @check_date
    ))
INSERT INTO stage2_checklist_detail
  (stage2_checklist_header_id, check_date, st2_chk_det_load_date, 
   inspected_by)
VALUES
  (@formHeaderId, @check_date, GETDATE(), @inspected_by)

SET @form_detail_id = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
    PRINT 'inserted detail record ' + CAST(@form_detail_id AS VARCHAR(50))
```

Comment: do you have any trigger associated to this sp?

Comment: "All of the data is exactly the same except for the id." In your check, you are looking for a matching ID. If its different, then a row will be inserted.

Comment: It's hard to see the potential for a duplicate insert in this section of code.  Is it possible that two threads of your application code are running this procedure at the same time?  They could possibly hit the same millisecond.  Or is there a loop inside the procedure?

Comment: Specifically, two threads could dodge the EXISTS check precisely because they hit the same millisecond. That would also explain the intermittent (or random) nature of the duplicate inserts.

Comment: It does seem like a user entry issue, is it possible for two people to be trying to insert the same data at the same time? What I would do is wrap the exists check data logic in a convert statement that gets rid of the millisecond difference and see if the fixes your duplicates.  Just a thought, there's other options too.

Comment: I think we need to see the whole procedure.  The part where you said: "@formHeaderId is grabbed earlier in the stored procedure" is a potential problem.

Comment: I added more from the stored Procedure.
@ scc, there is no trigger.
@ RandomUs1r, I thought of this as well but it is extremely unlikely that this occurs as only person can access the page that is calling this SP

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [similar case](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/transactsql/thread/d5f87abc-e303-484a-b40f-5639dfbe2efa/) where the developer was able to track the duplicate entries to simultaneous calls from different spids (which sidestepped the EXISTS check).  After experimenting with isolation levels and transactions - and trying to avoid deadlocks - it sounds like the solution in that case was to use sp_getapplock and sp_releaseapplock.

Answer (score 0):

In the `NOT EXISTS` check, you are looking for records that have both the same ID and the same date. So, if the combination of ID AND date does not exist in the table, the row will be inserted. 
In your description of the problem you state "All of the data is exactly the same except for the id". The ID being different will always cause an INSERT based on the logic you are using to check for existence.

Comment: I think OP is talking about stage2_checklist_detail_id, not stage2_checklist_header_id.  In this section of code we only see the variables (at)form_detail_id and (at)formHeaderId.

Comment: Yes, this is correct. The statement was intended to say "all of the data except for stage2_checklist_detail_id is the same". stage2_checklist_detail_id is an auto-increment primary key field which is generated upon the insert.


If there is a stage2_checklist_header_id and check_date already in the table, it should not insert another row.